# How to check if an ObjectId is present in array in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am creating a project using Node.js, where I have two models: **User** and **Project**.

Here's the Schema for Project model:

```
const ProjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        maxlength: 50,
        required: true,
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        maxlength: 800,
        required: true
    },
    contributors: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    }],
});
```

Now, for a project, I want to check if the current user is already present in the project's contributors. If the user is not present, then add the user, otherwise, Ignore.

How can I check that in an efficient manner?

Comment: "How can I check that in an efficient manner?" You code it. What have you tried so far? All you posted is your project schema and no effort to resolve your issue. BTW: In mongodb is mostley the `_id` key.

Comment: @Marc Code what? Run a loop to check one by one?

Comment: Do a simple "find", if it returns something the user exists, if not not...

Answer (score 0):

mongoose offers you the aggregate method which does pretty everything, in your case:

```js
const projects = ProjectModel.aggregate([
  { $match: {/* query for matching a small size of projects first(you should definitely do this) */} },
  { $unwind: "$contributors" },
  { $project: { contributor: "$contributors" } }, // This stage is actually optional
  { $match: { "contributor._id": /* contributor id you want to check */ } },
  { $count: "projects" }
]);
```

Now you can just check the variable and see **how many projects have the user in their contributors array**

I tested this dataset:

```json
[{
  "_id": 1,
  "name": "Project1",
  "contributors": [{
      "_id": 11,
      "name": "user1"
    }, {
      "_id": 22,
      "name": "user2"
    }]
}, {
  "_id": 2,
  "name": "Project2",
  "contributors": [{
      "_id": 22,
      "name": "user3"
    }, {
      "_id": 44,
      "name": "user4"
    }]
}]
```

With this query:

```js
const projects = ProjectModel.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: 1 } },
  { $unwind: "$contributors" },
  { $project: { contributor: "$contributors" } },
  { $match: { "contributor._id": 22 } },
  { $count: "projects" }
]);
```

The result:

```json
[{
  "projects": 1
}]
```

[Playground Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RO6W8Jfg9mE)

Answer (score 0):

Query

- find the project
- check if user `_id` is on the contributors array
- if it is do nothing (keep old value)
- else add the new user
- replace `2` with the user `id` and `{"_id": 2}` with the user document

*there is no performance problem here, it will be max 1 project i guess with that `_id` , you only do 1 test to see if its already contributor.

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70217541)

```js
update(
{"_id": {"$eq": 1}},   //find the project
[{"$set": 
    {"contributors": 
      {"$cond": 
        [{"$in": [2, "$contributors._id"]}, "$contributors",
          {"$concatArrays": ["$contributors", [{"_id": 2}]]}]}}}])
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) when updating your project document .

> $addToSet will only add element to array if it is not added .

```
let user_id = req.body.user_id;
let project_id = req.body.project_id;

let data_to_update = { $addToSet:{contributors: user_id}};

Project.updateOne({ _id:project_id },data_to_update).then((updated)=>{
    console.log('updated =',updated);
    return res.status(200).json(updated);
}).catch((err)=>{

});
```